# MySql search two columns same table sort by first colum

Tags: mysql, sql

This may be a simple SQL query, if I have a table like this:

```
books(
    id       int,
    title    varchar (255),
    description mediumtext
)
```

Summary: I need to search the title and description for the input "term" but sort the results first by title matches which considered higher rank for me then results by the results found from description search.

details: I need to search for the "terms" in the title column ordered by title and then search the description and sort their results by title, then join the results from searching on the title with the search on the description BUT keep the first search on title at the top.

the query steps:

```
result 1 = search title for terms sorted by title
result 2 = search description for terms sorted by title
result 3 = merge result 1, result 2 (union)
```

Comment: *higher score* where is the score?

Comment: What database are you really using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` to order first the results from title and then the results from description and then sort each group by `title`:

```
select * from books
where title like '%search%' or description like '%search%'
order by 
  case
    when title like '%search%' then 1
    when description like '%search%' then 2
  end, title
```

Since you tagged MySql only, you can write the same query simpler:

```
select * from books
where title like '%search%' or description like '%search%'
order by title like '%search%' desc, title
```

Comment: the first query worked, while the second gives myql error, I am using mysql.

Comment: Is it MySql or SQL Server?

Comment: If it is MySql then the query runs fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iL4DxA17V4sWAjw1AAr7D9/0. If it is SQL Server then it does not.

Comment: do not know what the error but it is mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.34, for Win32 (ia32)

Comment: the first one even works using: `order by 
  case
    when dream like '%سمك%' then 1 else 2
  end, dream`

Comment: The 2nd query should also work. Check the demo. Did you copy as it is or did you modify it?

Comment: It may be your table does not have data, the problem mysql does not say anything about the error, it just  says error.

Comment: I posted the link just to verify that there is no syntax error. I guess you get a syntax error right?

Comment: But 5.1.34 is a very old version of MySql (before 2010) and I really can't rememeber if it did or did not support boolean expressions to be converted to 0 or 1.

Comment: OK no problem I 'll use the first query as it works, I just thought I should tell you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use expressions in `order by`.  So:

```
order by (case when title like concat('%', @search_term, '%') then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when description like concat('%', @search_term, '%') then 1 else 2 end)
```

In MySQL, this can be simplified to:

```
order by (title like concat('%', @search_term, '%')) desc,
         (description like concat('%', @search_term, '%')) desc
```

Comment: @daliaessam . . . Why?  You don't know how to write a `select`/`from`?  I am curious why you didn't like this answer, which was posted several minutes before the other answer.